# Page view Controller in Android

Tags: android

How we can implement page view controller in Android like iPhone? Is there any control available in Android? Please give me any clue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written/extended a swipe/fling view for android with an iPhone like page controler at the bottom. 
You can download the [sources at github](https://github.com/fabsimilian/Android-Swipe-view-with-pager).

Comment: it is simple viewpager, we need page view controller like iphone, ie page folding effect

Answer (score 1):

[GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) has a PagedView component. Check out the demo app on the [Market](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.cyrilmottier.android.gdcatalog).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like ListActivity?
go ahead and search "ListActivity" in api docs.

Comment: I think List Activity is different thing... I am looking for Page View Controller..

Answer (score 0):

A view pager will help you in this situation.
Refer this link for android API documentation for the same:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide